# Split all desired values in string Django

Tags: python, django, string, split

Hi. I have a function in my `views` in which I have a variable and I use it in template.

```
 imagesj[str(i)]=str(j[0])
```

from which I get a value similar to this

```
{'Adele-1-Fuchsia-9': 'product/adele_1_fuchsia_1.jpg',
 'Jealyn-37-Brown-10': 'product/jealyn_37_brown_1.jpg'}
```

I need to get only `product/adele_1_fuchsia_1.jpg` and `product/jealyn_37_brown_1.jpg` which are dynamic values and they will be changed according to product. I need to replace the front part before product in string. How can I do this?

Comment: `dic = {'Adele-1-Fuchsia-9': 'product/adele_1_fuchsia_1.jpg', 'Jealyn-37-Brown-10': 'product/jealyn_37_brown_1.jpg'}


[x for x in dic.values() if 'product' in x]`

Comment: @theAlse why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo, it was too short :) to be an answer

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what your original data structure looks like, but If you have a dictionary like the one below:

```
dic = {'Adele-1-Fuchsia-9': 'product/adele_1_fuchsia_1.jpg', 'Jealyn-37-Brown-10': 'product/jealyn_37_brown_1.jpg'}
```

you can get the products-element by iterating the values:

```
print [x for x in dic.values() if 'product' in x]
```

this prints:

```
['product/adele_1_fuchsia_1.jpg', 'product/jealyn_37_brown_1.jpg']
```